# how secure is a digital signature?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, digital-signature, security

Digital signature, if I understood right, means sending the message in clear along with a hash of the message which is encrypted using a private key.

The recipient of the message calculates the hash, decrypts the received hash using the public key, then compares the two hashes for a match.

How safe is this? I mean, you can obtain the hash of the message easily and you also have the encrypted hash. How easy is it to find the private key used to create the Encrypted_hash?

Example:

```
Message            Hash    Encrypted_hash
-----------------------------------------
Hello world!       1234    abcd
Hi there           5678    xyzt
Bla bla            0987    gsdj
...
```

Given the Hash and the Encrypted_hash values, and enough of these messages, how easy/hard is it to find out the private key?

Answer (score 8):

Because of the algorithms used to generate the keys (RSA is the typical one), the answer is essentially "impossible in any reasonable amount of time" assuming that the key is of a sufficient bit length. As long as the private key is not stolen or given away, you won't be able to decrypt it with just a public key and a message that was hashed with the private key.

As linked to in @Henk Holterman's answer, the RSA algorithm is built on the fact that the computations needed to decrypt the private key - prime factorization being one of them - are hard problems, which cannot be solved in any reasonable amount time (that we currently know of). In other words, the underlying problem (prime factorization) is an [NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29) problem, meaning that it cannot be *solved* in polynomial time (cracking the private key) but it can be *verified* in polynomial time (decrypting using the public key).

Comment: I don't believe it is known for sure to be in NP.

Comment: @GregS: I believe that prime factorization itself has been proven to be NP, though feel free to illustrate if I am incorrect. I should have been clearer that I was referring to that, not RSA as a whole.

Comment: @GregS: I think Prime factorization is trivially within NP, since there is an obvious polynomial-time algorithm to check a candidate factorisation (just multiply it out).  What has *not* been shown is that it is NP-complete.

Comment: @caf: You're right, I should have said it has not been proven that it is not in P, although nobody expects it to be in P.

Comment: @GregS: Sure, but that's self evident too, since if it was proven not to be in P then that would constitute a proof that P != NP, which is still an open problem (the events of last weekend notwithstanding!).

Comment: @GregS: Perhaps what you mean is that it hasn't been shown that factorisation is NP-complete, meaning that even if P != NP, factorisation could still be P.

Comment: @caf: I cannot find any reference that indicates that factorization outside of P implies P!=NP. Nor can I find a reference that indicates factorization in P implies P=NP.

Comment: @GregS: We agree that factorization is obviously within NP.  If you have a proof that factorization is *not* in P, then you have shown a problem which is within NP but not within P - which proves that NP is distinct from P.

Comment: @caf: OK, I'll have to admit that you understand this better than I. I was following the conjecture that factoring may be outside of the P and NP-complete classes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladner%27s_theorem.

Comment: @GregS: Yep - which means that if you prove factoring *is* in P, then you don't prove anything about P versus NP (but you've still broken RSA! ;)

Answer (score 6):

Ciphers developed before electronic computers were often vulnerable to "known plain-text" attack, which is essentially what is described here: if an attacker had the cipher-text *and* the corresponding plain-text, he could discover the key. World War II-era codes were sometimes broken by guessing at plain-text words that had been encrypted, like the locations of battles, ranks, salutations, or weather conditions.

However, the RSA algorithm used most often for digital signatures is invulnerable even to a "chosen plain-text attack" when proper padding is used (like [OAEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAEP)). Chosen plain-text means that the attacker can choose a message, and trick the victim into encrypting it; it's usually even more dangerous than a known plain-text attack.

Anyway, a digital signature is safe by any standard. Any compromise would be due to an implementation flaw, not a weakness in the algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

A digital signature says nothing about how the actual message is transferred. Could be clear text or encrypted.

And current [asymmetric algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsa) (public+private key) are very secure, how secure depends on the key-size.

An attacker *does* have enough information to crack it. But it is part of the 'proof' of asymmetric encryption that that takes an impractical amount of CPU time: the method is computationally safe.

Answer (score 4):

What you're talking about is known as a "known plaintext" attack. With any reasonably secure modern encryption algorithm known plaintext is of essentially no help in an attack. When you're designing an encryption algorithm, you assume that an attacker will have access to an arbitrary amount of known plaintext; if that assists the attacker, the algorithm is considered completely broken by current standards.

In fact, you normally take for granted that the attacker will not only have access to an arbitrary amount of known plaintext, but even an arbitrary amount of *chosen* plaintext (i.e., they can choose some text, somehow get you to encrypt it, and compare the result to the original. Again, any modern algorithm needs to be immune to this to be considered secure.

Answer (score 1):

> Given the Hash and the Encrypted_hash values, and enough of these messages, how easy/hard is it to find out the private key?

This is the scenario of a [Known-plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack): you are given many plaintext messages (the hash) and corresponding cipher texts (the encrypted hash) and you want to find out the encryption key.

Modern cryptographic algorithms are designed to withstand this kind of attack, like the [RSA algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA), which is one of the algorithms currently in use for digital signatures.

In other words, it is still extremely difficult to find out the private key. You'd either need an impossible amount of computing power, or you'd need to find a really fast algorithm for factorizing integers, but that would guarantee you lasting fame in the history of mathematics, and hence is even more difficult.

For a more detailed and thorough understanding of cryptography, have a look at the literature, like the Wikipedia pages or Bruce Schneier's [Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html).

Answer (score -1):

For a perfectly designed hash it is impossible (or rather - there is no easier way than trying every possible input key)